# How to put .opezeppelin folder at desired directory in hardhat?

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I am using Openzeppelin upgradable with hardhat. By default the plugin store .openzeppelin folder at root but I have running multiple environments so would like to set .openzeppelin folder at the desired location.
How to do it with hardhat?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the deployment chain a new .json file (`.openzeppelin/<network>.json`) will be created and stored automatically inside the `.openzeppelin` folder so there's no need to duplicate it for each of your environments. (e.g. deploying on Polygon Mumbai will result in a different .json file than the one created when deploying on Polygon)